# Unity Shader Blend like ugui Outline

Tags: unity, c#, shaders, alpha-blending

Unity UGUI `Outline` it create fourfold vertexs, So I wirte shader to optimization ( vertex only create once ), 
And I want to Keep one pass . (one drawcall)

[image]

There are four character , all character font size are same.
but this character edge look a little small.

I write shader like this

```
 fixed4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
        {
            fixed4 color = (tex2D(_MainTex, IN.texcoord) + _TextureSampleAdd) * IN.color;

            float4 pClipRect = float4 (IN.uvOriginXY, IN.uvOriginZW);
            color.a *= IsInRect(IN.texcoord, pClipRect);
            half4 val = half4(_OutlineColor.r, _OutlineColor.g, _OutlineColor.b, 0);//(r,g,b,0)

            //black characters
            val.a += SampleAlpha(2, IN);
            val.a += SampleAlpha(5, IN);
            val.a += SampleAlpha(8, IN);
            val.a += SampleAlpha(11, IN);

            val.a = clamp(val.a, 0, 1);

            //blend
            color = (val * (1.0 - color.a)) + (color * color.a);

            return color;
        }
```

And the lower right picture is create by UGUI `Outline` it look like white color overlap black color , How can I do like this ?

The problem probably from here : `color = (val * (1.0 - color.a)) + (color * color.a);`

What should I do to make it look like UGUI`Outline`? thanks.

Comment: Your offsets are off, too. The upper-right and lower-left "clones" don't line up vertically (or horizontally) with the upper-left and lower-right "clones". Also, `_OutlineColor.r` (and `.g` and `.b`, ditto `val.r`) should also work, which makes it easier to read. I *suspect* that you aren't adjusting the alpha value correctly for the places where the white character is semi-transparent but the outline characters aren't.

Comment: @Draco18s thank for suggest , I edit my code to be more readable. 
yes the problem probably  is the semi-transparent place how to blend , If I split two pass (one pass draw black ) ( one pasee draw white color ) , it will solve my problem ( But drawcall go up)

Comment: Right now it appears that you are adding together all of the alpha values, you probably either want to multiply them or use only the largest.

Comment: @Draco18s I think I slove my problem and I post a answer thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Draco18s suggest , I think I Slove this problem , this problem is a about alpha value missing. So just choose the larget alpha. like this:

```
            half orginA = color.a;
            color = (val * (1.0 - color.a)) + (color * color.a);
            color.a = max(orginA,val.a);// choosing larger one
```

[image]